# sum column values from one table in relation with values of column from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

So, I have 3 tables

```
Table H

hotelNo | hotelName

H1 | Greenslopes
H2 | Wynsor
H3 | Red Hills

>Table R

roomNo |hotelNo | price
R1 | H1 | 60
R2 | H1 | 50
R3 | H1 | 75
R4 | H1 | 120
R5 | H1 | 95
R1 | H2 | 85
R2 | H2 | 45
R3 | H2 | 90
R4 | H2 | 80
R5 | H2 | 100
.
.
.

>Table B

hotelNo | roomNo
H1 | R1
H2 | R1
H3 | R1
H4 | R2
H5 | R4
H1 | R3
H2 | R1
H3 | R2
H4 | R2
H5 | R3
H1 | R1
H2 | R5
H3 | R1
H4 | R5
H5 | R1
.
.
.
```

Now, I need to get the total price for the Rs that H1 has in Table B

The Answer should be something like

```
hotelNo | Total
H1      | ###
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
SELECT B.hotelNo, sum(R.price)
FROM B
INNER JOIN R
    ON B.hotelNo = R.hotelNo
WHERE B.hotelNo = 'H1';
```

But, it doesn't work. It just sum everything from Table R

Then, I tried this (didn't work either):

```
SELECT B.hotelNo, B.roomNo + (SELECT sum(R.price)
                                FROM R
                                WHERE B.hotelNo = R.hotelNo) as TotalPrice
FROM B
WHERE B.hotelNo = 'H1';
```

HELP ME PLEASE!

Comment: Which result do you want for this sample data?

Comment: This:
```
hotelNo | Total
H1      | ###
```
But it is solved already. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query does not work then you might be missing an additional condition in the ON clause:

```
SELECT b.hotelNo, SUM(r.price) total_price
FROM Booking b JOIN Room r
ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
WHERE b.hotelNo = 'H1'
GROUP BY b.hotelNo -- you can omit this line in SQLite
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6w77KPMWF3beFBauQdSsEx/5).
Result (for your sample data):

```
| hotelNo | total_price |
| ------- | ----------- |
| H1      | 195         |
```

Comment: Hi forpas. Your suggestion is perfect. I tested and it works. Thank you, I honestly didn't know I could add AND to the ON clause.
Again, thank you very much.

Comment: The ON clause must contain a Boolean expression, simple or complicated to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you want:

```
SELECT b.hotelNo, sum(r.price)
FROM Booking b INNER JOIN
     Room r
     ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
WHERE b.hotelNo = 'H1';
```

Although it is malformed (because the unaggregated column in the `SELECT` is not in the `GROUP BY`), SQLite might accept it.  I prefer using an explicit `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT b.hotelNo, sum(r.price)
FROM Booking b JOIN
     Room r
     ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelNo
WHERE b.hotelNo = 'H1'
GROUP BY b.hotelNo;
```

Comment: You 1st query is an exact copy of the OP's 1st query. In your 2nd query you added a GROUP BY clause which is not needed in SQLite. The 2 queries are exactly the same. What is the point of your answer?

Comment: Hi Gordon. The first query doesn't work, I tried it myself in sqlite, and it sums the whole column 'price' from table R.
And your second suggestion does the same. Thank for trying, but you answered with my own solution (which doesn't work)

Comment: @EddSoul24 . . . You are saying that the `WHERE` clause is ignored?  I think you might be misinterpreting the results.